# authGSSServerInit extremely slow

Tags: python, linux, active-directory, single-sign-on, kerberos

I am implementing a single sign-on mechanism for a Flask server running on Ubuntu 16.04 that authenticates users against an Active Directory server in the Windows domain.

When I run the example app from https://github.com/mkomitee/flask-kerberos/tree/master/example on the Flask server, I can access the Flask server from a client computer that's logged in, the server correctly negotiates access and returns the name of the logged in user. However, this is very slow, taking about two minutes.

Following the steps of what happens in `flask-kerberos`, I found that the process stalls at the [`authGSSServerInit` step](https://github.com/mkomitee/flask-kerberos/blob/master/flask_kerberos.py#L70). I can reproduce the behaviour using the following minimal progam:

```
import kerberos
rc, state = kerberos.authGSSServerInit("HTTP@flaskserver.mydomain.local")
```

The initalisation finishes successfully, but it takes about two minutes again.

I have successfully registered the service principal (`HTTP/flaskserver.mydomain.local`) on the AD server and exported the keytab to the Flask server. I can get a ticket granting ticket on the Flask server using `kinit -k HTTP/flaskserver.mydomain.local`. I can also verify passwords in Python using the `kerberos` library:

```
import kerberos
kerberos.checkPassword('username', 'password', 'HTTP/flaskserver.mydomain.local', 'MYDOMAIN.LOCAL'
```

This runs correctly and almost instantly.

What could be the cause for the delay in running `kerberos.authGSSServerInit`? How do I debug this?

Comment: Have you taken/examined a wireshark trace?

Comment: I haven't taken a trace (simply because I don't have any experience with that), but your keyword helped me google for the problem. It turns out that this stalling was caused by a reverse DNS lookup failing. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The delay was caused by a failing reverse DNS lookup for the hostname. `host flaskserver` correctly returned the IP, but `host <ip-of-flaskserver>` returned a `Host <ip-of-flaskserver>.in-addr.arpa not found: 2(SERVFAIL)`.

As described at https://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-1.13/doc/admin/princ_dns.html, disabling the reverse DNS lookup in the `krb5.conf` solved the problem:

```
[libdefaults]
    rdns = false
```